# freeradius - how can i add attributes for all groups

Tags: sql, attributes, freeradius

I would like to create an entry in a SQL db, that say use a attribute for all groups.
Example:

- table radgroupreply 
  groupname   attribute       op  value
  all     Session-Timeout     =   86400
- table radusergroup
  username    groupname   priority
  16M_Profile all         11

Normal 16M entrys works fine... or do I must set this entrys in radgroupcheck, too?

But that new entry was not used. Complete entries are:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `radcheck`;
CREATE TABLE `radcheck` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `attribute` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `op` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '==',
  `value` varchar(253) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `username` (`username`(32))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `radcheck` (`id`, `username`, `attribute`, `op`, `value`) VALUES
(1, 'testuser', 'Cleartext-Password',   ':=',   'test),
(2, 'testuser', 'User-Profile', ':=',   '16M_Profile');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `radgroupcheck`;
CREATE TABLE `radgroupcheck` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `groupname` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `attribute` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `op` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '==',
  `value` varchar(253) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `groupname` (`groupname`(32))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `radgroupcheck` (`id`, `groupname`, `attribute`, `op`, `value`) VALUES
(1, '16M',  'Framed-Protocol',  '==',   'PPP');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `radgroupreply`;
CREATE TABLE `radgroupreply` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `groupname` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `attribute` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `op` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '=',
  `value` varchar(253) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `groupname` (`groupname`(32))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `radgroupreply` (`id`, `groupname`, `attribute`, `op`, `value`) VALUES
(1, '16M',  'Mikrotik-Rate-Limit',  '=',    '1M/16M'),
(2, 'all',  'Session-Timeout',  '=',    '86400'),
(3, 'all',  'MS-Primary-DNS-Server',    '=',    '217.11.***.***'),
(4, 'all',  'MS-Secondary-DNS-Server',  '=',    '***.***.***.***'),
(6, 'all',  'Idle-Timeout', '=',    '30'),
(8, 'all',  'Framed-Route', '=',    '217.11.***.***/24 0.0.0.0 1');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `radreply`;
CREATE TABLE `radreply` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `attribute` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `op` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '=',
  `value` varchar(253) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `username` (`username`(32))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `radreply` (`id`, `username`, `attribute`, `op`, `value`) VALUES
(1, 'testuser', 'Framed-IP-Address',    '=',    '217.11.***.***');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `radusergroup`;
CREATE TABLE `radusergroup` (
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `groupname` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `priority` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  KEY `username` (`username`(32))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `radusergroup` (`username`, `groupname`, `priority`) VALUES
('16M_Profile', '16M',  10),
('16M_Profile', 'all',  11);
```

How do I add the attribute?

Comment: Kudos for including your DB code, BUT it is...very unclear...as to what you are asking. Can you possibly ask it in a DIFFERENT way?

Comment: hi i would add special attributes for all user groups, if i use 16M instead of all, all attributes works fine, but it i use 16M i must add all attributes for all Profiles, well 16M is only 1 Pofile i have many profiles 50M 100M ... and on all i would use special attributes like all in exsample, but declaration does not work here. understand? regards